# SQL (MySQL etc), what is the difference about length string (1-256) and (0-256)?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Thanks for reading my post.

I wanna know, what is the difference between length (1-256) and (0-256) in sql and how to store them in database?. I was asked to design a db from the information below.

```
example case:
 1. field : city, type : string, length (1-256) 
 2. field : email, type : string, length (0-256)

from my perspective:

    1-256 = 256 character
    0-256 = 257 character
```

Thanks a lot for any corrections or suggestions!

Regards,
Denny

Comment: Maximum 256 characters in either case, no? In the second case you are told that the string could be empty string.

Comment: where do you define that ?

Comment: I for one don't understand the question. `varchar(0)` would be an invalid type definition. So what do you mean with `0-256`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, guys. I got this one from my assignment which has some rules,
example :
1. city string length (1-256)
2. email address string length (0-256)

Comment: Could you provide the detail rule definition in your SQL in mysql Database.  I'm curious how to use it.

Comment: Is this a question about MySQL, or PostgreSQL?

Comment: example ( field : city, type : string, length (1-256) ), ( field : email, type : string, length (0-256) ). I was asked to design the db from the above information.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is the information about the minimum and maximum possible length of some data.

Both will fit inside `varchar(256)` datatype. As for the minimum length (0 and 1) you can either ignore it or enforce it using `check length(city) > 0` constraint as there is no such thing as `varchar(1, 256)` dataype.

Comment: Thank you so much Salman for helping me to understand